# Using nested std::async with std::condition_variable in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, condition-variable, stdasync

I have got `Worker` classes and a `Handler` class to create an abstraction layer for jobs already. I wanted to use `std::async` to pour some asynchrony into the mix but I got some weird behaviour from my Visual Studio 2012 (update 1).

My class hierarchy is as follows:

- `Worker` is an abstract class with `Init` and `Work` as pure virtual methods.
- `BasicWorker : Worker` is simply using `printf` for some output.
- `GroupWorker : Worker` is an aggregation of other workers.
- `Handler` holds on to a `Worker` to do some job.

Then I call several `std::async` methods in which I create workers and a handler, I call for handler in a nested `std::async` call and, I wait for initialization (`std::condition_variable` here) of the worker and then I stop the handler.

In the end I wait for all of the `std::future`s to finish.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <future>
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

struct Worker
{
    virtual ~Worker() { }
    virtual void Init() = 0;
    virtual void Work() = 0;
};

struct BasicWorker : public Worker
{
    virtual ~BasicWorker() { }
    virtual void Init()
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tInit: %d\n", std::this_thread::get_id());
    }

    virtual void Work()
    {
        printf("\t\t\t\tWork: %d\n", std::this_thread::get_id());
    }
};

struct GroupWorker : public Worker
{
    GroupWorker()
    {
        workers.push_back(std::make_shared<BasicWorker>());
    }

    virtual ~GroupWorker() { }

    virtual void Init()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        {
            workers[i]->Init();
        }
        initEvent.notify_all();
    }

    virtual void Work()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < workers.size(); ++i)
        {
            workers[i]->Work();
        }
    }

    void WaitForInit()
    {
        //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> initLock(initMutex);
        //initEvent.wait(initLock);
    }
private:
    std::mutex initMutex;
    std::condition_variable initEvent;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Worker>> workers;
};

struct Handler
{
    static const int Stopped = -1;
    static const int Ready = 0;
    static const int Running = 1;

    Handler(const std::shared_ptr<Worker>& worker) :
        worker(worker)
    { }

    void Start(int count)
    {
        int readyValue = Ready;
        if(working.compare_exchange_strong(readyValue, Running))
        {
            worker->Init();

            for(int i = 0; i < count && working == Running; ++i)
            {
                worker->Work();
            }
        }
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        working = Stopped;
    }
private:
    std::atomic<int> working;
    std::shared_ptr<Worker> worker;
};

std::future<void> Start(int jobIndex, int runCount)
{
    //printf("Start: %d\n", jobIndex);
    return std::async(std::launch::async, [=]()
    {
        printf("Async: %d\n", jobIndex);
        auto worker = std::make_shared<GroupWorker>();
        auto handler = std::make_shared<Handler>(worker);

        auto result = std::async(std::launch:async, [=]()
        {
            printf("Nested async: %d\n", jobIndex);
            handler->Start(runCount);
        });

        worker->WaitForInit();
        handler->Stop();

        result.get();
    });
}

int main()
{
    const int JobCount = 300;
    const int RunCount =  5;
    std::array<std::future<void>, JobCount> jobs;

    for(int i = 0; i < JobCount; ++i)
    {
        jobs[i] = Start(i, RunCount);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < JobCount; ++i)
    {
        jobs[i].get();
    }
}
```

My problem is:

- If I uncomment the lines in `WaitForInit@GroupWorker` function then my nested asynchronous function calls are not made until all first level asynchronous function calls are made
- While waiting `std::condition_variable` if I increase the number of jobs, creation of new threads feels like getting exponentially slow. For my trial below 100 jobs there exist some asynchrony but above 300 it is completely sequential to create jobs.
- Then if I uncomment the `printf` line in `Start` method, all nested asynchrony works like a charm

So,

- What am I doing wrong in usage of `std::condition_variable`?
- Why creating jobs gets slower for like 100s of threads? (this question is optional, seems like a problem of OS and can be fixed with a smart thread-pool concept)
- What has `printf` to do with any of this? (I tried deleting all `printf` calls in the case of a race condition and I put a breakpoint in the code but no help. It is the same case with `std::cout` too)

Edit: 
I have added launch policy (as suggested by Jonathan Wakely) for assuring the creation of a thread. But that did not help either. I am currently creating a `std::thread` and calling `thread::join` function for waiting inside the first level async.

Comment: 1) why are you using printf? there is cout. 2) when I try to compile using gcc 4.7 and run your code, I get an exception, meaning that you did something wrong even with the commented out code

Comment: 1) Since outputs are given in different threads `cout << "Init" << id << endl` interferes with other threads. Making such call atomic requires `stringstream` and its kind of verbosity. I am using `printf` for presentation purposes here. 2) It was working in my VS2012 and on http://ideone.com/YK6pxU. In my gcc (mingw) this does not even compile so I cannot help with that at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N.B. it's OK to call `printf`, but not to assume `std::thread::id` is convertible to `int`. You could make that slightly more portable like so:

```
inline long tol(std::thread::id id)
{
  std::ostringstream ss;
  ss << id;
  return stol(ss.str());
}
```

(This still assumes the string value of `std::thread::id` can be converted to `long`, which isn't required, but is more likely than assuming an implicit conversion to `int`)

> What am I doing wrong in usage of std::condition_variable?

You have no "condition" that you're waiting for and no synchronisation to ensure the call to `notify_all` happens before the calls to `wait`.  You should have a member variable that says "this worker has been init'd" which is set by `Init`, and only wait on the condition variable if it's not true (that flag should be atomic or guarded by a mutex, to prevent data races).

> Why creating jobs gets slower for like 100s of threads? (this question is optional, seems like a problem of OS and can be fixed with a smart thread-pool concept)

Because with hundreds of threads there is a lot of contention for shared resources and a lot of pressure on the OS scheduler, so the implementation probably decides to start returning deferred functions (i.e. as though `std::async` was called with `std::launch::deferred`) instead of async ones.  Your code assumes `async` will not return deferred functions, because if an async worker and its nested async worker are both run as deferred functions the program could deadlock, because the outer function blocks waiting for the nested one to call `Init` but the nested function never runs until the out one calls `result.get()`.  Your program is not portable and only works on Windows because (if I understand correctly) the MSVC `async` uses a work-stealing thread pool which will run a deferred function if a thread becomes available for it. **This is not required by the standard.**   If you want to force each worker to have a new thread, use the `std::launch::async` policy.

> What has printf to do with any of this? (I tried deleting all printf calls in the case of a race condition and I put a breakpoint in the code but no help. It is the same case with std::cout too)

It imposes a slight delay, and probably some form of unreliable ordering between threads since they are now contending, and probably racing, for a single global resource. The delay imposed by the `printf` might be enough for one thread to finish, which releases its resources to the thread pool and allows another async worker to run.

Comment: I have tried setting launch policy but it didn't help, I am going to stick to the idea anyways. And for race condition on the variable I have written something like this (incomplete WinAPI wannabe): http://ideone.com/BTyqRK. I guess it is going to solve deadlock problem. For the last `printf` issue: even if I am launching with async policy the system does not respond. I tried `wait_for@future` function for 1ms and looped as long as the result is `deferred` but it resulted in exceptions and errors.

Comment: That code has nothing to do with WinAPI. There's no need to use a mutex **and** an atomic type.  Since you need the mutex to use with the condition variable just use a mutex. N.B. the conventional way to refer to a C++ member function is `future::wait_for` not `wait_for@future`

Comment: It was a quick recode and test. Did not have enough time to think about it. I was trying to mimic manual-reset-event from windows api. But I guess this is going to be another question:) thanks for your help